# posh-git - Start-SshAgent not recognized on new computer

Tags: git, powershell, ssh, posh-git

I've set up a brand new computer with PowerShell 7 and posh-git. When trying to run profile.ps1 on startup the `Start-SshAgent` command fails, resulting in cmdlet not recognized. `Import-Module posh-git` works fine, I see the command line prompt changes. In fact, everything else in profile.ps1 from my old computer is working fine.

I tried checking that my environment variables are set up. I'm able to run `ssh-agent.exe` from the PowerShell prompt, so that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSH functions have been moved to a separate module: https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-sshell.

(You might mean `Start-SshAgent` rather than `StartSsh-Agent`.)